# Error during Socket.io installation

Tags: node.js, windows, installation, socket.io, npm

I was wondering if someone could help me out here. I keep getting the following errors during the installation of Socket.io on windows 7 64 bits: http://pastebin.com/YMQgWNRu

I've done the following things already:

- Added Nodejs path variable
- Added Python path variable
- Installed Microsoft windows SDK
- Played around with the visual studio settings

The Socket.io folder ends up being created in the modules folder (inside Nodejs), but anything fails to find the socket.io module.

Edit: I noticed some dutch language in the error log: "Het systeem kan het opgegeven bestand niet vinden." means "The system could not find the requested file".

Comment: *"but anything fails to find the socket.io module"* can you provide a few examples of *"anything"*?

Comment: Anything with require('socket.io') basically.

Comment: did you install gyp? do you have multiple versions of vs installed? (check your programs and features, if you do, you'll need the flag that specifies the correct version. In my case i had versions all the way from 08)

Comment: I installed Gyp, I even removed and reinstalled the latest version. I've only got VS 2015 installed as far as I can see.

Comment: I think I narrowed the problem down to not having "CL.exe" in my visual studio installation folder.

Comment: I fixed the problem mentioned above (by reinstalling Visual Studio 2015 with C++), but now got another error: "Cannot load language resource clui.dll"

Comment: This is driving me crazy. I've tried 3 different visual studios by now (with the use of --msvs_version=xxxx), all returning different errors.

Comment: i wish i could help, : / it works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't believe that I finally fixed it, but I did. For anyone reading this and going through the same nightmare here is what I did:

1. First of all I made the mistake of trying to install the Socket.io inside the NodeJS folder. It should be in installed in your project folder.
2. I uninstalled visual studio (and 2010 C++ redis.) and started from Visual Studio 2010 and went from there using '--msvs_version=xxxx'. At Visual Studio 2013 Express my installation was for some reason successful.